# Can't Set PhpMyAdmin Password (XAMPP + Windows 7)

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

sorry if this is on the wrong board (probably should be on "security").

I have tried setting username and password from this page `http://localhost/security/index.php` (the second part "XAMPP DIRECTORY PROTECTION (.htaccess))", everytime it says that it was successful but when I go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, it is always open and not asking for username and password. Also, when I open `http://localhost/security/index.php` "PhpMyAdmin is free accessible by network" is still showing as "unsecured".

I checked C:\XAMPP\security - xammp.users file, and the user name and password is there.

Already tried cleaning cookies and restart XAMPP.

Here is my config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'mypassword';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'mypassword';
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

EDIT: Additional info: I was also had the same problem when setting "MySQL admin user root", had to manually edit / put the password at the config file, couldn't do it from here `http://localhost/security/index.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your `config.inc.php` file, to have something like this:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']            = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']                 = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']             = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']      = false;
```

Then you'll have to enter password each time you login first time (for session).

Setting `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';` forces phpMyAdmin to use username and password stored in your configuration file (`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works because now it is asking me for username and password, also the security page shows that it is "secured" (took a glance before I logged out / clearing cookies). But when I tried to login, I failed when I used the password from $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'mypassword';. What should I do?

Comment: If you set configuration like that, then you're logging to PMA using _username and password from MySQL database_, not from PMA's configuration. In other words, you should access PMA, when it is "open" (not secured by password), go to `Users` section, create some users, remember their logins and passwords, then "secure" your PMA with above configuration and then login only using logins and passwords, you have just set (for the users you have just created). BTW: If you want to "thank" here -- upvote and/or accept my answer using arrows and checkmark around score.

Comment: `controluser` and `controlpass` are phpMyAdmin's internals and you should not change them / use them in any way.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks again, especially for all the explanation, I appreciate it. All works now.